# Recv() (on client app) not receiving all messages sent from server . (IP/TCP)

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXvde.png)I'm hoping to send messages of different lengths to a client while conserving messages' borders. To do that , the server sends a special message whenever the next message he's sending is of a different size.
Client Side , a  realloc call on the receptive entity is made, which seems to be working alright.

the messages are sending correctly from the server (the return value of send() is not -1) , however, the recv on client side only reads a (random) number of letter , usually not receiving the last messages (up to 8 un-read but sent messages), but other times seem to be working perfectly. This doesn't always happen, and there is not particular pattern.
I've tried some tests, and found that recv (..., msg_peek) return value is -1 , while messages are being sent to the buffer.

I have used the flag MSG_PEEK on the receiving loop (while) .

```
while (recv(sock,message_rec,lg_attendue,MSG_PEEK)>0)
    {
      
    

       if (!Bal_Detection_Lettre(message_rec)) //detects a message containing info about the size of the next one
     {

       expected= Bal_Detection_Longueur_Message(message_rec,  30) ;
       message_rec=(char *) realloc(message_rec , expected *sizeof(char));
       printf("expected : %d\n" , expected);
       recv(sock,message_rec,lg_attendue,0);
     }
       else {

     recv(sock,message_rec,expected,0);
     display_message(message_recu,expected) ; //function displaying the message
       }

    }
  
  printf("expected : %d\n",expected) ; 
  
}
```

the server side code is nothing special, and uses send() to send messages before closing the connexion.

Comment: You should really save the return value of `recv()` and check that value, make sure the data is completely received. Also, if you want to receive full packet in TCP within single call to `recv()`, you probably need `MSG_WAITALL`, __not__ `MSG_PEEK`.

Comment: You may have to add some length identifier in your packet to be sent by `send()`. So that the other side will have information: "_how many bytes the packet should be received_".

Comment: @AmmarFaizi the client know how many bytes it should receive (expected variable), since the server starts by sending a special form of message that states it. I don't understand how  ```MSG_WAITALL``` would work, especially since I really want my messages to be received while respecting their borders and not the capacity of my recv buffer.

Comment: The 'special message' is one byte, no longer, yes?

Comment: @MartinJames the special message is always 30 bytes (that's the default buffer (message_rec) size)

Comment: Anyway, I can't see the exact problem you have. I hope you can give more detailed info about the packet structure to be received. Also, to me, it is unclear how `expected` variable is calculated.

Comment: Note that, there is no guarantee that `recv(fd, buffer, size, flag)` will fill the `buffer` with `size` bytes even if the other side `send()` with the `size` bytes, your `recv()` may only get partial bytes of that. So you can't ignore the `recv()`'s return value.

Comment: It is also unclear why `recv()` returns `-1` in your case. This is indeed an error, but what error?
----
To find out the reason of why `recv()` returns `-1`, you need to check the `errno` variable from `<errno.h>` and use `strerror()` to translate the `errno` number from `<string.h>` (IOW, print the error message from `recv()`).
----
This can be done by `if (recv_ret_value == -1) printf("Error: %s", strerror(errno));`.

Comment: I don't understand your protocol.  You have a 30-byte header that specifies the length of subsequent messages, but how does 'Bal_Detection_Lettre(message_rec)' know how many bytes have been loaded into the buffer by 'recv(sock,message_rec,lg_attendue,MSG_PEEK)'?  You have thrown away that info by your incomplete handling of the result returned by recv()  which, if positive, could be anything from 1 to 30, (assuming a 30 byte send).

Comment: @AmmarFaizi the message send is a message of 30 bytes starting with an identification number (necessary for the application but irrelevant here.) Then the messages ends with the length of the message to be expected. the expected variable  is calculated with a function that read this special message and extracts the size information , the function seems to be working correctly. I'll add a screenshot of my output. (note that I'm sending 2 more messages that recv is not getting.)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of text. You can just copy and paste text as text, and then everyone can read it normally.

Comment: @MartinJames I added a variable to stock the return value of ```recv(sock,message_rec,lg_attendue,MSG_PEEK) ``` always returns 1 while in the loop than 0 once it breaks out. (I should specify that lg_attendu starts with the value 30). Bal_Detection_Lettre(message_rec) tests if the message is a special length indicating message or a data message. Given that Bal_Detection_Lettre(message_rec) and Bal_Detection_Longueur_Message(message_rec,  30)  work perfectly, I assumed that I am receiving 30 bytes when a special message is sent

Comment: @AmmarFaizi the recv set value isn't taking -1 in my current tests , it's at 0  . I tried adding like you suggested ```if (recv_ret_value == 0) printf("Error: %s", strerror(errno));``` replacing -1 with 0 I got this : _Error: Connection reset by peerexpected : 40_

Comment: `recv()` returns `0` means the connection has been closed. You should really provide more detailed information so that it makes sense to be answered.

Comment: BTW, connection reset by peer. So the other side has `close()`'ed the connection when you are reading from its file descriptor.

Comment: @AmmarFaizi I was just trying to see that after I read your previous message. Could it be a time lag thing ? since the speed of the arrival of messages into the buffer is faster than the reading speed of those messages ? My program seems to be working fine after I removed close(fd) from the server side (that is sending)

Comment: Yes, it is possible due to network latency, sending packet via network takes time, and TCP is a stream.
----
I suspect it is because you don't take care of `recv()` return value. So that the packet to be received is not always handled properly. But who knows, your entire question is still unclear anyway.

Comment: Just so you know, in `SOCK_STREAM`, when the server calls `send(fd, "aaa", 3, 0);` and `send(fd, "bbb", 3, 0);`.
---
And then the client calls `recv(fd, buffer, 6, 0);`. Then it is possible that your `buffer` will contain "aaab" (4 bytes), and then `recv()` will return `4` (may also return other numbers below 7). So you should really save and compare the return value of `recv()`. Always do that, and call `recv()` again while the packet has not been fully received.

Comment: You needn't use `MSG_PEEK` at all. Simply do a fixed-length `recv`, then a variable-length receive based on the header received in the previous. But as @AmmarFaizi points out, make sure you receive exactly the number of bytes you're expecting - no more no less